# Unable to save data with Many to Many mapping with join table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have User and Course entities with many to many mapping. The join table `Registration` contains two extra fields and hence requires its own table. When I try to save the user, I am getting the below error. I do not know where I am going wrong.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [2] value by reflection : [class com.classpath.edukart.model.UserCourseId.courseId] setter of com.classpath.edukart.model.UserCourseId.courseId
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:72) ~[hibernate-org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeLongFieldAccessorImpl.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:52) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    ... 89 common frames omitted
```

`User`

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "userId")
@Builder
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private long userId;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String emailAddress;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = ALL)
    private Set<Registration> courses;


    public void registerCourse(Course course){
        Registration registration = new Registration(this, course);
        if(course.getUsers() == null){
            course.setUsers(new HashSet<>());
        }
        if (this.courses == null){
            this.courses = new HashSet<>();
        }
        course.getUsers().add(registration);
        this.courses.add(registration);
    }
}
```

`Course`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id", "name"})
@ToString(of = {"id", "name", "price","duration", "rating"})
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    private double price;

    private int duration;

    private double rating;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
    private Set<Registration> users;
}
```

`Registration`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users_courses")
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"user", "course"})
public class Registration {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserCourseId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @MapsId("userId")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @MapsId("courseId")
    private Course course;

    @Column(name = "registration_date")
    private LocalDate registeredDate;

    private int percentageCompleted;

    private Registration(){}

    public Registration(User user, Course course){
        this.user = user;
        this.course = course;
    }
}
```

`UserCourseId`

```
@Embeddable
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class UserCourseId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="user_id")
    private long userId;

    @Column(name = "course_id")
    private long courseId;

    public UserCourseId(){}

    public UserCourseId (long userId, long courseId){
        this.userId = userId;
        this.courseId = courseId;
    }

    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public long getCourseId() {
        return courseId;
    }

    public void setCourseId(long courseId) {
        this.courseId = courseId;
    }
}
```

Client program

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void run(String... args) {
    User johnDoe = User.builder()
                        .firstName("John")
                        .lastName("Doe")
                        .emailAddress("johndoe22@gmail.com")
                        .address(new HashSet<>()).build();


    Course java = Course.builder().name("Java").duration(24).price(15_000).build();
    Course python = Course.builder().name("Python").duration(14).price(25_000).build();

    johnDoe.registerCourse(java);
   // johnDoe.registerCourse(python);

    userRepository.save(johnDoe);


    log.info("Before saving to the db :: {}", johnDoe.getCourses());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
@Column(name="user_id")
private long userId;

@Column(name = "course_id")
private long courseId;
```

You don't want the user_id/course_id. You want:

```
@ManyToOne User user;
@ManyToOne Course course;
```

No offense, but I am merely helping you to shoot yourself in the foot quicker and more painful. Since you have not overriden equals(Object o) and hashCode() this is going to explode pretty soon.

Comment: But I have made use of EqualsAndHashCode from Lombok package. Wouldnt that take care?

Comment: Simple answer: No. Longer answer: The implementation of equals has to match the concept of equality in the database. So two entities should only be considered equal iff they are mapped to the same row in the table - or in practical terms: If they have the same primary key. This not (!) what Lombok does by default. Maybe somebody could write a Lombok extension to deal with JPA Ids but AFAIK such an extension does not exist.
You amy want to look at this blog post for a longer explnation of the problems: https://mdeinum.github.io/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/